# Question about the complex log

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about the following theorem:

> suppose that $D$ is simply connected and that $0\notin D $. Choose $z_0 \in D $, fix a value of $\log z_0 $ and set $$ f\left(z\right)=\intop_{z_{0}}^{z}\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta}+\log z_{0} $$
> Then $ f $ is an analytic branch of $\log z $ in D.

Here's the proof from my complex analysis book:

$f $ is well-defined since $1/\zeta $ is an anlytic function of $\zeta $ in $D $, and hence the integral along any two paths from $ z_0 $ to $ z $ yield the same value.
Furthermore, $f'(z)=1/z$, so $ f $ is analytic in $ D $.
To show that $exp(f(z))=z$ we consider $$ g\left(z\right)=ze^{-f\left(z\right)} $$

Since $ g'\left(z\right)=e^{-f\left(z\right)}-zf'\left(z\right)e^{-f\left(z\right)}=0 $, g is constant and $ g\left(z\right)=g\left(z_{0}\right)=z_{0}e^{-f\left(z_{0}\right)}=1 $

Hence, $ e^{f\left(z\right)}=z $.

My question is:

Why do we need $ D $ to be simply connected ? I cant see where we used it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " the integral along any two paths from $z_0$ to $z$ yield the same value" - think why this holds

Comment: If it wasn’t simply connected, there would be holes and the integral would fail for some $z$

Comment: What is your definition of "simply connected"?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $D$ is simply connected is exploited in ensuring that the integral of $1/\zeta$ between any two points in $D$ depends only on the endpoints, i.e. it is not path dependent. This is necessary for $f(z)$ to be well-defined.

"Simply connected" means that there is only one homotopy class, i.e. any two closed curves in $D$ can be mapped to each other by free homotopy. This is a condition for Cauchy's theorem, which ensures the path-independence of the integral, to apply.

If $D$ is not simply connected, it still could be the case that the integral is well-defined, e.g. if there is only a removable singularity, but we can't say anything for sure.